# Law of Cosines Manipulation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm supposed to use law of cosines on $S_1S_2P$ in the following diagram:

[triangle diagram http://puu.sh/5zDtv.jpg](http://puu.sh/5zDtv.jpg)

To arrive at the following equation:

$$
\frac{r_2}{r_1} = [1 - 2(\frac{a}{r_1})sin(\theta) + (\frac{a}{r_1})^2]^\frac{1}{2}
$$

I decided to work backwards from this equation, and got to:

$$
r_2^2 = r_1^2 + a^2 - 2ar_1cos(\theta)
$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed, or if I'm even on the right track. $\theta$ in this case would be 90$^{\circ}$, which doesn't seem right to begin with.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot read the picture.

Comment: Try to seriously increase both the size and the clearity of the picture. I can't understand a thing, either.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've just updated the picture and made it readable.

Comment: I don't think the picture is correct because both the lines make $\theta_m$ with the horizontal and still they intersect

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but if you look closely, you'll see that hte middle line doesn't make $\theta_m$ with the horizontal, but with the a point on the base of the triangle which is slightly above the horizontal.